# How to copy a batch of relative Google Sheet formulas and paste in different location with original cell references?

Tags: google-sheets, absolute-value

I need to copy a load of rows of cells which contain various relative formulas and to past them in a different location but with those same cell references as in the original location.

I understand that the '$' char does this at an individual level, but how can i do this with a bul cut/copy & paste?

Thanks

Comment: The `excel` answer lies in VBA which has nothing to do with `google-spreadsheet` . If you want a google-spreadsheet-specific answer, remove `excel` from the tags.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, helpful.